# Read the inputs of a user-defined function in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am defining a function that will take a new function from a user and do some "maths". I am clearly blank about this user defined function because I don't know what his/he inputs to his function are. I would need to know these user inputs later in the "maths" that my function is doing.

This is my function, for example,

```
function userfunction(x,y)
     return x+y
end
```

Just for example, I am clearly unaware of the inputs `x` and `y` in the above user-defined function. I use this function to do some maths in my function but I need to be aware that `x` and `y` are the inputs of the `userfunction`.

```
function myfun(userfunction::Function)
    ....do so maths...
    #but some maths here need to know the inputs of "userfunction"
end
```

Is there a function in Julia that can read the inputs of another function? Like for instance, read the inputs of "userfunction" and return an array?

Comment: Could you at least provide examples of the inputs you're expecting? You might be interested in the `parse` function but it's  hard to say more without further information.

Comment: @NilsGudat I have edited the explanation of my question

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, although I'm still not fully clear - do you want to use the values of `x` and `y` in `myfun`, by just passing `userfunction`? Could you extend your example to a simple case of "here's what the user practically inputs" (and where) and "here's what I want to do with this input"? In general it seems to me like what you're asking is not possible (i.e. just passing a function object to `myfun` will not give you any information about specific values that this function object might be called with)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but if you want to know what kinds of arguments your `userfunction` takes, you can get that.

First, remember that `userfunction` can have multiple method, each with different arguments (yay, multiple dispatch!). To get an array of them all, do:

`meths = collect(methods(div))`

Then, for each method, you can look up its signature:

`signature = meths[1].sig`, which will give you a type `Tuple{typeof(div), Int,  Int}`, for example.

Then, discard the first element of the signature to get the arguments:
arguments = `Tuple(signature.parameters[2:end])`, to get the argument types: `(Int, Int)`.

That's pretty complicated, and perhaps there's an easier way.

Comment: the result of this gives me the types of inputs. But what I want is to know the inputs themselves. So like `x` and `y` and not `(Int, Int)`

Comment: Afaik this is not in general possible - although I'm still not sure how you actually get a hold of `userfunction` (i.e. where does the user input it and what of this input can you observe)

Comment: Generally, `userfunction` must be a function taking certain inputs as arguments. So I would like to know this arguments before doing maths in `myfun`

Comment: What does "must be a function taking certain inputs as arguments" mean? Jakob gave the solution for when "certain inputs" means the types of inputs are restricted. I still don't understand where the user inputs `userfunction` and how you get a hold of it. Without knowing this it's hard to say whether you could revocer the *values* (rather than the types) of `x` and `y` in `userfunc(x,y)` after the fact.